# AWS RDS showing outdated data for Multiple AZ instance (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, high-availability, amazon-rds

My RDS instance was showing outdated data temporarily.

I ran a `SELECT` query on my data. I then ran a query to delete data from a table and another to add new data to the table. I ran a `SELECT` query and it was showing the old data.

I ran the `SELECT` query AGAIN and THEN it finally showed me the new data.

Why would this happen? I never had these issues locally or on my normal non AZ instances. Is there a way to avoid this happening?

I am running MySQL 5.6.23

Comment: You just enabled the "multi-az" setting on the database correct? You didn't create any read replicas?

Comment: @MarkB Yes think so, I can't find anything about read replicas under my instance, it just has a secondary zone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As embarrassing as this is... it was an issue in our Spring Java code and **not** AWS.

A method modified a database entity object. The method itself wasn't transactional but was called from a transactional context which would persist any changes on entities to the database.

It looked like it was rolling back changes, but what it was doing was just overwriting data. My guess is it overwrote the data a while ago so until someone tried to modify it we just assumed it was the correct data.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Amazon RDS Multi-AZ FAQs](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#multi-az-deployments), this might be expected.

Specifically this:

> You may observe elevated latencies relative to a standard DB Instance deployment in a single Availability Zone as a result of the synchronous data replication performed on your behalf.

Of course, it depends on the frequency of the delays you're observing and what is the increased latency you're seeing, but an option would be to contact AWS support in case the issue is frequently reproducible.

Comment: This quote doesn't say, to me, what it apparently says to you.  Elevated latency != data inconsistency.  Elevated latencies refers to slower writes, since the data is replicated. It doesn't mean inconsistent reads.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot OK, I think I didn't give enough details about my thought process. "Synchronous data replication" means to me that RDS applies the data to the first instance and then synchronously to the replica. My understanding is that, in order to guarantee atomicity, until both instances have committed the new value, SELECT queries should return the old value. So, an increased latency, in my understanding, might mean that you will get data from before the commit happened. You call it inconsistent data. I'm not exactly sure it is inconsistent.

Comment: An inconsistent read is, by definition, retrieving stale data after you have written new data.  In MySQL, this shouldn't be possible.  If OP were using different connections, then this is likely related to transactions, and not multi-AZ.  I can't conceive of a mechanism in MySQL that would allow an inconsistent read after a commit (even an implicit one) -- any latency should only be able to delay the *completion* of the statement's execution, until which time subsequent queries on the same connection would be impossible.

Comment: It would be nice to have some confirmation from the OP on how the queries were executed (connection- and transaction-wise).

Comment: It was an issue with our server code overwriting the data change which made it seem like it was a database issue.
Upvoting this answer though because I found it helpful during debugging